# Reduce text size on Windows 8.1 tablet

Tags: windows-8.1, display-settings, windows-tabletpc, tablet-pc

I have an HP Stream 7 (tablet) with Windows 8.1. The screen size in desktop mode is a little difficult to work with, and I was exploring changing up the resolution to make things a little easier to touch.

In the "Make text and other items on the desktop smaller and larger" setting, I upped the size, a little bit too much, and now the screen is completely unusable.

I can barely navigate around the desktop, and am unable to revert back to 100% or another size, because I can't position the settings window in a way that I can save it. I can't use the keyboard because the tray is taking up the entire bottom of the screen so I don't see the keyboard icon, and can't change the tray settings because its save button is also unclickable with this resolution.

Any thoughts as to how I can change the setting back, short of factory resetting, or buying a bluetooth keyboard to hook up to move things around (which I don't even know for sure would work)?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, barely...

- PC Settings (in the "modern" interface, not the desktop)
- Ease of Access
- Keyboard
- On-Screen Keyboard (On)

This forces the on-screen keyboard to show up and stay up on the desktop. With this, I was able to open the screen resolution window, and then press Enter to save, after some shuffling around of windows.